# How to predict the brier score for a cox regression?

Tags: r, machine-learning, mlr

I am using the [mlr](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/release/html/index.html) package to do machine learning in R. I am using a the [cvcoxboost](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/CoxBoost/versions/1.4) algorithmn on a dataset and would like to calculate the brier score of the output.

This should work, since `listMeasures(cvcoxboost.tsk)` also lists the measurement `ibrier`. The entire code looks like this:

```
cvcoxboost.lrn = makeLearner("surv.cv.CoxBoost") 
cvcoxboost.tsk = makeSurvTask(data = data, target = c("time", "event"))
cvcoxboost.mod = train(cvcoxboost.lrn, cvcoxboost.tsk, subset = data.train) 
cvcoxboost.tsk.pred = predict(cvcoxboost.mod, task = cvcoxboost.tsk, subset = data.test)

listMeasures(cvcoxboost.tsk) # "iauc.uno" "featperc"    "ibrier"      "timeboth"  "timetrain"   "timepredict" "cindex.uno"  "cindex"  

performance(cvcoxboost.tsk.pred, measures = mlr::cindex)
performance(cvcoxboost.tsk.pred, measures = cindex.uno, model = cvcoxboost.mod, task = cvcoxboost.tsk)
performance(cvcoxboost.tsk.pred, measures = mlr::ibrier, model = cvcoxboost.mod, task = cvcoxboost.tsk)
```

...and I receive the error `No method for evaluating predicted probabilities from objects in class: CoxBoost`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ibrier only works for certain learners that are supported by the pec package like randomForestSRC or cox. This is currently not well documented enough, but you can look into the pec package to see which models are supported.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really thought it was my mistake that it does not work. I will try to implement brier for the other models myself then